# What is the difference between <content> and <shadow> Tag in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, html5-template

While reading the paper tabs component, I came to know that there is a tag `<shadow></shadow>` I tested it with one of my component. And it is working similar as `<content></content>` tag. So my question is what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polymer, the shadow tag is use when you [extend another polymer element](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#extending-other-elements), the parent template will be inserted inside the shadow tag. Whereas the local dom will be inserted inside the content tag

Comment: Thats a clearer answer imho since the answer by @Adi was more general than this one which is polymer related, such as teh question was. Long story short, you have my upvote!1 yey

Answer (score 0):

They  fulfill the same purpose of acting as an insertion point for content from outside the custom element and both are intended to being used on web component.

But where as `<shadow>` tag is used when you need to create more than one shadow root in a component.

More about these tags at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Shadow
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content